# Upgrading Xubuntu from 18.04 to 20.04 completely messed up all the libraries

Tags: apt, upgrade, 20.04

The system can boot to the point where I can interact with the shell, but every program I tried so far has broken dependencies. `ping` is missing `libnettle`, `dig` is missing `libdns`. `apt-get` cannot resolve the host of the Ubuntu package repository. Another example of missing libraries: `less` won't work because it's missing `libtinfo`.

Actually, all of the libraries sort of exist in the system, but they are all wrong versions.

Basically, the update drove the system into the state, where to restore it is more work than to reinstall.

This is less of a question than a warning: do not upgrade, at least not from 18 to 20.

The question part: how could this have been prevented? What should I have to check in order to recognize that the update is, essentially, broken and, what, if anything, could anyone do in a situation like this beside reinstalling the whole thing?

---

Upon request:

The system was a vanilla Ubuntu, no extra packages, nothing. It was installed about a year ago, and since then the laptop wasn't used.

Before upgrading the system, it requested only that I run `apt-get upgrade`, which I did.

There were no warnings or anything special during the system upgrade process. At the end, it asked me to reboot the computer. After reboot, it was already dysfunctional.

Comment: Can you let us know what error you trying to solve ? Kindly let us know what steps you took.

Comment: @KKPatel read the last paragraph of my question?

Comment: @user535733 what do you want to rule out? My question is "what to look for in order to recognize a broken upgrade". No, I didn't have anything non-ubuntu installed. It was, actually, a vanilla Xubuntu 18. Literally, nothing was installed outside the system. This laptop was sitting in the cupboard for a year or so, and today I decided to upgrade it.

Comment: @user535733 system gave no feedback. It happily chugged along with the upgrade, until it was no longer able to boot

Comment: Here you did not clear define what exactly dysfunction here with some logs, output or screenshot would be good to understand better what is broken.

Comment: @KKPatel seriously? How much more clear can it be? `ping` is a dynamically linked executable, it needs a library `libnettle`, but this library doesn't exist. `ping` was installed from one package, but the library it needs was installed from another package, and the versions of the requirement and the actual don't match.

Comment: In your steps you don't show if you ran `sudo apt update` before you ran the `sudo apt upgrade` so that it knew what files to update before running the upgrade.  I have upgraded 2 Xubuntu 18.04 installations here with very minimal problems after the upgrade process was done to 20.04.  Usually once the damage like that has been done and you can't get the apt application to work properly to install / reinstall the messed up apps you would be looking at a clean installation.

Comment: Show us /var/log/apt/term.log if you really want to know what happened. Otherwise you're asking us to guess.